# Xcode 8 Beta 6 text is choppy and distorted

Tags: xcode, antialiasing, xcode8-beta6

After I installed Xcode 8 beta 6 I immediately realised that the text is very aliased. Even though it is of minor importance, I want it to be anti aliased. Zoom into the image and you will see that it is clearly choppy and aliased.

[image: As you can see, the text is aliased]

My MacBook Pro 13" is currently running on MacOSX El Capitan 10.11.6
Xcode 8 Beta 6

Comment: I flagged this question as off-topic, because it is not a programming question. You might get help on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: anti-aliasing is a software term, so technically it is on-topic

Comment: Have you tried to change the font of your IDE?

Comment: Yes i did try to change the font

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i found the answer to my question:

defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode NSFontDefaultScreenFontSubstitutionEnabled -bool NO

just paste that into the Terminal :D